# Generic Editable WPF PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, propertygrid, xceed

I am trying to get a WPF PropertyGrid that enables generic editing of object values. I have datatypes that contain either primitives or other types that only contain primitives.

I have been trying to use WpfToolkit's PropertyGrid (wpftoolkit.codeplex.com) and threw ExpandableObject all over the relevant types in my code. The PropertyGrid properly displays the data and expands hierarchical types, but none of the changes to non-primitive properties are actually saved to the composed objects.

After attempting to add more attributes and working with triggered events, the possible solutions have been non-trivial. Seemingly needlessly so.

I only have basic familiarity with WPF/XAML. My intent was to quickly throw together a data entry tool for the designers on our team. Is there a straightforward way to generically enable such hierarchical editing for my types in a WPF control?

Comment: Have you tried this 100% free open source one: https://github.com/SoftFluent/SoftFluent.Windows (disclaimer, I wrote this).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've changed to the SoftFluent PropertyGrid, but hierarchical expansion doesn't seem to be happening? I've change all of my types to now inherit from AutoObject, does anything else need to be done?

Sexy theming btw :)

Comment: If you need to expand sub object, you can add a         [PropertyGridOptions(EditorDataTemplateResourceKey = "ObjectEditor")] to the property. Just look at the sample for more. All known editors (datatemplates) are defined in propertygrid.xaml. Also n you can use the github issues directly if you have any question.

Comment: In my opinion having the old WinForms PropertyGrid on a WindowsFormsHost is probably the easiest. In my personal experience of changing the behaviour of the Property Grid (Writing custom Editors/TypeConverters) is the easiest by far in the WinForms propertyGrid. However, you lose the styling look and feel, as well as you can't render any WPF controls on top of WinForms controls (Busy Indicators, overlays, etc). I can show you some examples of what type of editors you can create, and how to implement these on the PropertyGrid if you'd like.